# crontab running twice but ps ax shows only one crond process

Tags: linux, cron

I am trying to run a crontab which executes a bash script which triggers mail command. I have done only one entry in crontab for my user. Also doing ps ax | grep cron results only one crond process. I don't know why i am getting mails twice

Cron logs

```
Aug  7 14:38:10 centos crond[29299]: (CRON) INFO (RANDOM_DELAY will be scaled with factor 85% if used.)
Aug  7 14:38:11 centos crond[29299]: (CRON) INFO (running with inotify support)
Aug  7 14:38:11 centos crond[29299]: (CRON) INFO (@reboot jobs will be run at computer's startup.)
Aug  7 14:40:01 centos CROND[29376]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Aug  7 14:50:01 centos CROND[29940]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Aug  7 14:59:01 centos CROND[30388]: (test_user) CMD (bash /home/test_user/dev/mail_test_user.sh)
Aug  7 15:00:01 centos CROND[30585]: (test_user) CMD (bash /home/test_user/dev/mail_test_user.sh)
Aug  7 15:00:01 centos CROND[30586]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Aug  7 15:01:01 centos CROND[30775]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug  7 15:01:01 centos run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[30775]: starting 0anacron
Aug  7 15:01:01 centos run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[30787]: finished 0anacron
Aug  7 15:01:01 centos run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[30775]: starting 0yum-hourly.cron
Aug  7 15:01:01 centos run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[30795]: finished 0yum-hourly.cron
```

Crontab list

```
@reboot autossh -M 8000 -f -N -R 9000:localhost:22 remote_user@192.168.0.3
@reboot autossh -M 8002 -f -N -R 9001:localhost:5901 remote_user@192.168.0.3
@reboot autossh -M 8004 -f -N -R 9002:localhost:80 remote_user@192.168.0.3
0,59 * * * * bash /home/vikas/dev/mail_test_user.sh
```

Contents of mail_test_user.sh

```
echo "I am up :)))" | mail -s "Notification : test_user@centos.localdomain [STAG]" foobaar22@gmail.com
```

ps aux | grep cron results

```
root     29299  0.0  0.0 126300  1692 ?        Ss   14:38   0:00 /usr/sbin/crond -n
test_user    31650  0.0  0.0 112640   964 pts/0    S+   15:13   0:00 grep --color=auto cron
```

Any luck why the hack this is happening ?

I also tried rebooting and restarting crond but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in setting up cronjob it should be */59 instead of 0/59.

Answer (score 0):

The second line is result of your `grep` command. This is process of **grep** command not your **cronjob** process. Because it matches your search criteria.

Comment: yes thats what i said only one crond process is running still its firing cron job twice as you can see in cron logs

Comment: Cron works right as I see. You specified in crontab file following rule: 0,59 * * * *. Thats mean to run your job every hour at 59 minutes and 00 minutes. Like 14:59 or 15:00. And that is what happening. Your cron started first at: Aug  7 14:59:01. And second time on: Aug  7 15:00:01.

Comment: oh its my bad don't know how i turned */59 into 0,59 thanks :)